# Django admin: Format fields in list, but keep sortable?

Tags: django-models, django-admin

I keep numeric fields like "size", "width", "height" in my database. Now I would attach units like "KiB" or "pixels" to them when showing them in the change list. This could easily be achieved by adding callables such as "size_formatted" etc to list_display. However, these are no longer sortable.

Is there a way around this limitation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read here - [ModelAdmin.list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) (read a lot to get to the point ;) )

you need to add **admin_order_field** attribute to your function

```
class YourAdminCLass(admin.ModelAdmin)
   [...]
   def size_formatted(self, obj):
          return "whatever you need"
   size_formatted.admin_order_field = 'size'
```

Comment: Hooray, a christmas present! Thanks for this.

Comment: wow, never knew about `admin_order_field` , thanks a bunch!